# 100% width of a child div inside a parent div not coming

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, parent-child

How to show 100% width of a child div inside a parent div if i am using scroll for parent div.

Below is a picture have a look this picture for idea. As show in second picture, i want something like that.

[Have a look this picture for idea http://www.fzkforum.com/CHILD-ISSUE.JPG](http://www.fzkforum.com/CHILD-ISSUE.JPG)

**Below is my html code.**

```
<!--/*main div starts*/-->
<div style="width:480px; margin:auto; border:solid 2px; padding:10px;">

<!--/*parent div starts*/-->
<div style="overflow:scroll; height:300px; padding:10px; " >

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>hthtrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>hthtrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>     
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>hthtrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>hthtrh</td>

<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>hthtrh</td>      <td>htrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>hthtrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrh</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>htrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>rhtrht</td>
<td>htrhth</td>
<td>
link
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--/*child div starts*/-->
<div style=" border: solid 1px #ccc;">i want this  div 100% is it possible?  </div>

<!--/*child div ends*/-->
</div>
<!--/*parent div ends*/-->

</div>
<!--/*main div ends*/-->
enter code here
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using table and table-cell properties you can achieve this. But you need to add some more divisions in your code like below.

```
 <div style="width:480px; margin:auto; border:solid 2px; padding:10px;">

 <!--/*parent div starts*/-->
 <div style="overflow:scroll; height:300px; padding:10px; " >
 <div style="display:table">
 <div style="table-row">
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>

  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrh</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>htrht</td>
  <td>
   link
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 <!--/*child div starts*/-->
 <div style="display:table-row">
 <div style=" border: solid 1px #ccc; display:table-cell;">i want this  div 100% is it possible?  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <!--/*child div ends*/-->
 </div>
 <!--/*parent div ends*/-->

 </div>
```

[**Have a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/56hUf/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a class for child-div and have its width as 480px;

```
 .child{
  width:480px;
}
```